# Отключение/подключение функций в цикле python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите как реализовать следующую задачу: имеется цикл while в нем при определенных условиях (в зависимости от того что в файле config) должны быть функции с определенными аргументами (функция одна и та же, но аргументы разные) причем эта функция может быть минимум 1 и максимум 9. Приведу пример:

```
while True:
    funk(4,9)
    funk(1,3)
    funk(6,2)
    funk(7,5)
```

Как можно подключать определенные функции в приведенном примере? (прошу не пинать за подобный вопрос)

Comment: Если функция одна и та же, может стоит отобрать аргументы по условию из конфига, а потом уже с ними вызвать функцию?

Comment: Прочитать конфиг и затем уже в зависимости от условия вызывать нужную функцию

Comment: @Clark Devlin , количество функций зависит от конфига, но как их вызывать? Конечно можно через if , но это слишком громозко будет так как много комбинаций

Comment: В цикле вызывать

Comment: @SacredSacred Простым циклом со счётчиком, а аргументы можете хранить в массиве.